# Bound on Truncated Alternating Harmonic Series

Tags: analysis, inequality, summation, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

I'm trying to prove the following inequality

$$\sum _{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\log (2)<\frac{1}{4N+1}.$$

Most of the traditional inequalities I've seen for harmonic numbers aren't tight enough to prove this, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Vague idea: Look at the Taylor polynomial for $\log(1-x)$. Sorry if that's not helpful, but it just is something I noticed.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer my mistake, it's negative for $N$ odd, but positive for $N$ even. I edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: Is it ?$\sum _{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}+\log (2)<\frac{1}{4N+1}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the taylor series of $\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}$, we have

$$\ln(2)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$$

then
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} + \ln(2) &= \sum_{n=2N+1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \\
&= \sum_{k=N}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{(-1)^{2k}}{2k+1}+\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{2k+2} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=N}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+2} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=N}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)} \\
&= \sum_{k=N}^{+\infty} \frac{4}{(4k+2)(4k+4)} \\
&< \sum_{k=N}^{+\infty} \frac{4}{(4k+1)(4k+5)} =\sum_{k=N}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{1}{4k+1}-\frac{1}{4(k+1)+1}  \right) = \frac{1}{4N+1}\\
\end{align}